# Eclipse content assist: filter by "contains the phrase" instead of "starts with the phrase"

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete, eclipse-plugin, content-assist

If you start typing when the content assist is activated, content assist will only filter the suggestions based on the starting letters.

However, suppose that there is an object and we need to see if any of its methods contain a specific phrase in any parts of their names (not just checking if they start with that phrase).

Is there any way to configure the content assist or is there any plugin out there to provide that functionality for Eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders) project includes [subwords completion](http://eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#completion-engines) which seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

Keep in mind that with the upcoming 2.1 release (together with Eclipse Luna on the 25th of June, 2014), the subwords completion is no longer activated by default. Go to *Preferences > Code Recommenders > Completions* and activate the *Subwords-Completion Processor*.